# Linear regression on raster images - lm complains about NAs

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, raster, lm

I'm sure this can be fixed with few bytes, but I've spent hours on this simple thing and can't get out of it. I don't use R often.

I have 5 asciigrid files that represent 5 raster images. Some pixels do have values, other do have NAs. For example, the first image might be something like:

```
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
NA  NA  2   3   NA
NA  0.2 0.3 1   NA
NA  NA  4   NA  NA
```

and the second might be:

```
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
NA  NA  5   1   NA
NA  0.1 12  12  NA
NA  NA  6   NA  NA
```

As you can see, NA position is always the same and I'm 100% sure about that. What I'm willing to do:

- read the files with `read.asciigrid()`;
- get their values in a long array, using `values()` from the `raster` package;
- create a matrix with 5 rows, each of them holding the values of the corresponding map;
- linear fit each column and get the coefficients. Each column will represent a pixel, and will have 5 values corresponding to the 5 maps.
- create two new raster images with the coefficient values.

**I'm stuck at `lm`**. Specifically, it says: `Error in lm.fit(...): 0 (non-NA) cases`. However, from what I know about the imput maps, there should be either columns with **all** NAs or columns with **no** NA at all, like as follows:

```
NA   NA   NA   NA   0.2  2    NA  ... (lots of other columns)
NA   NA   NA   NA   2    2.1  NA
NA   NA   NA   NA   3    0.5  NA
NA   NA   NA   NA   12   6    NA
NA   NA   NA   NA   0.4  2    NA
```

I'd expect the output to be:

```
NA   NA   NA   NA   ..   ..   NA
```

so I can create a new raster image with the coefficients and keep the NA position. Where am I wrong? Pasting my code below. Thank you.

```
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(fields)
names = c('...','...','...','...','...')
x = c(10,20,30,40,50)
x = log(x)
y = vector('list',length=length(x))
rasters = vector('list',length=length(x))
for (name in names) {
  ind = which(name == names)
  rasters[ind] = read.asciigrid(name)
  rasters[ind] = raster(rasters[[ind]])
  y[[ind]] = values(rasters[[ind]])
}

y = t(simplify2array(y))
lModel = lm(y ~ x) // Error here!
```

This is the output of `str(y)`:

> num [1:5, 1:1260630] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ... (at some point there will be numbers here)

### Edit

Thanks to @RobertH I learned about `raster::stack` and `raster::calc`. I have tried:

```
x <- log(c(10,20,30,40,50))
fun <- function(y) { lm(y ~ x)$coefficients }
r <- calc(s, fun)
```

Getting an obscure `Cannot use this function` on a `.calcTest` call. I looked at `raster:::.calcTest` with no success. I have tried managing the case where all `y` values are `NA`, like so:

```
fun = function(y) { 
  if (any(!is.na(y))) { 
    lm(y ~ x)$coefficients
  } else { 
    NA
  }
}
r <- calc(s,fun)
```

And now It works for some minutes, but then I'm getting `Error in setValues(out, x) : values must be numeric, integer, logical or factor`. However it is common to set NA to raster values! I can't see what's wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you can get the raster data

```
library(raster)
names = c('...','...','...','...','...')
s <- stack(names)
y <- values(s)
```

You could now do something like this.

```
x <- log(c(10,20,30,40,50))
# need to exclude the rows that are all NA
i <- rowSums(is.na(y)) < ncol(y)
coef <- apply(y[i, ], 1, function(y) lm(y ~ x)$coefficients)
aa <- matrix(NA, ncol=2, nrow=length(i))
aa[i, ] <- coef
b <- brick(s, nl=2)
values(b) <- aa
```

But you do not need to do that. To do regression like this, I would do

```
fun <- function(y) { lm(y ~ x)$coefficients }
r <- calc(s, fun)
```

But because you have cells with only NA values (across the layers) this will fail (like in the apply above). You need to write a function to catch these cases:

```
funa <- function(y) { 
    if(all(is.na(y))) {
        c(NA, NA)
    } else {
        lm(y ~ x)$coefficients 
    }
}
r <- calc(s, funa)
```

Or for a much faster approach

```
X <- cbind(1, y)
invXtX <- solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X)
quickfun <- function(i) (invXtX %*% i)
m <- calc(s, quickfun) 
names(m) <- c('intercept', 'slope')
```

See ?raster::calc

Comment: Thanks for input. I manage to use stack to create a RasterStack object, but when I call calc, I get - Error in `.calcTest(x[1:5],fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply): cannot use this function`. Not really self-expainatory.

Comment: (no matter if I use your first or second approach, always getting *cannot use this function*)

Comment: You did not provide a reproducible example, so you can't expect the answer to actually work. But you did mention the NA values, which I ignored; I have edited the answer. The fast approach should have worked respectively.

Comment: I didn't expect the answer to work at the very first try :-) you seem to know the subject and I'm sure we'll sort this out. I will let you know as soon as I can try, c(NA,NA) might be what I was missing.

Comment: yup, but why not use the faster (perhaps 100x) approach

Comment: Worked, thank you. Because I'm not used to that syntax and I don't really understand it. Add some comment if you wish. Also I need to run this command only once. Took some 15mins today but at least I knew where I was going :-)

Comment: Your `funa` should be a `function(y)`, not `function(x)`, no?